# Why isnt my program returning the correct result for Rabin-Karp substring searching algorithm?

Tags: c

I have to implement the Rabin-Karp string searching algorithm.
I think there is something wrong with my `rkhash_next` function. My professor told us to compute the next hash value in the string using this equation:

```
yi+1 = 256^m-1*Y[i+1] + 256^m-2*Y[i+2] + ... + Y[i+m]
     = 256 * ( 256^m-2*Y[i+1] + ... Y[i+m-1]) + Y[i+m]
     = 256 * ((256^m-1*Y[i] + 256^m-2*Y[i+1] + ... Y[i+m-1]) - 256^m-1*Y[i]) + Y[i+m]
     = 256 * ( yi - 256^m-1 * Y[i]) + Y[i+m]
     = 256 * yi - 256^m * Y[i] + Y[i+m]
```

I did this, but my program keeps giving me surprising hash values as it "rolls" through the string. Here is my general code for my `rkhash_substring_match`:

```
int rk_substring_match(const char *pattern, const char *doc, int *first_match_ind)
{
    int plength = strlen(pattern);
    int dlength = strlen(doc);
    int i,j,x;
    int counter = 0;

    int first_match = 0;
    first_match_ind = &first_match;

    long long hash = 256;
    long long *h;

    long long phash = 0;
    long long dhash = 0;

    for (x = 0; x <= plength-1; x++)
        hash *= 256;

    phash = rkhash_init(pattern, plength,h);
    dhash = rkhash_init(doc, plength,h);


    for(i = 0; i <= dlength - plength; i++) {
        if (phash == dhash) {
            for (j = 0; j < plength; j++)
                if (doc[i+j] != pattern[j])
                    break;
            if (j == plength && counter == 0)
                first_match = i;

            if (j == plength)
                counter++;
        }

        printf("%lld\n", dhash);
        dhash = rkhash_next(dhash,hash,doc[i + 1], doc[i+plength]);

    }

    return counter;


}
```

In my class, long long variables are used to store hash values and 256^m for later usage in the program. Below is rkhash_init which generates the hash value and stores 256^m in the value of h:

```
    long long rkhash_init(const char *charbuf, int m, long long *h)
{

    int i,j;
    long long value = 1;
    long long hash = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        value *= 256;

    h = &value;
    long long val = value;

    for (i = 0; i < m -1 ; i++) {
        value = value/256;
        hash += mmul(value, charbuf[i]);
    }

    hash += charbuf[m-1];

    return hash;
}
```

And here is the problem child, rkhash_next:

```
long long  rkhash_next(long long curr_hash, long long h, char leftmost, char rightmost)
{
    return madd(msub(mmul(curr_hash, 256),  mmul(leftmost, h)), rightmost);
}
```

madd, msub, and mmul are functions given to us by the professor. They perform modulus arithmetic after completing either addition, subtraction or multiplication. For example, here is the madd function:

```
long long madd(long long a, long long b)
{
    return (a + b) % PRIME;
}
```

Can anyone please help me find out why my program is not working!?

Comment: What is your pattern? What is your doc? A short complete example doesn't need to be much more code than you've posted but would make this a much better, and perhaps more likely to be answered question.

Comment: `first_match_ind = &first_match;` serves no purpose - dead code.

Comment: @RetiredNinja doc is "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...b..aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" and pattern is "...b"